# Unit test initializes class without calling parameters, how do I get the parameters into the class?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working with Linked Lists in python, and the UnitTest our professor gave us calls C = Course(), but asserts the values after. This is what they use to grade, but I can't find a way to call the class then wait for the variables, and apply them to the class without parameters so it doesn't crash. Thoughts? Am I missing something obvious?
Tried to only include the relevant code. If people need full code for clarification or just for kicks/giggles let me know.

```
import courselist
import course

    def load_data(data):
    with open(data) as f:
        for line in f:
            dline = line.strip().split(",")
            C = course.Course(dline[0],dline[1],dline[2],dline[3])
            course_list = courselist.CourseList()
            course_list.insert(C)
    return course_list

def main():
    data = "data.txt"
    full_list = load_data(data)
    print(full_list.__str__())

main()
```

```
class Course:

    def __init__(self, c_num, c_name, c_hour, c_grade):
        self.c_num = c_num
        self.c_name = c_name
        self.c_hour = c_hour
        self.c_grade = c_grade
        self.next = None
```

```
class TestEmptyCourse(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_course_creation(self):
        # make sure that an empty course is correct
        c = Course()
        self.assertEqual(c.name(), "")
        self.assertEqual(c.number(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(c.credit_hr(), 0.0)
        self.assertEqual(c.grade(), 0.0)
        self.assertEqual(c.next, None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something obvious... *Hangs head in shame* For those interested here's how to fix it. It's always when you ask for help that you get it just in time to look like an idiot haha. Thanks to those to checked it out. If someone has an alternate solution I'll be sure to upvote you

```
class Course:

    def __init__(self, num=0, cname="", c_hr=0.0, cgrade=0.0, next=None):
        self.num = num
        self.cname = cname
        self.c_hr = c_hr
        self.cgrade = cgrade
        self.next = None

    def number(self):
        return int(self.num)

    def name(self):
        return str(self.cname)

    def credit_hr(self):
        return self.c_hr

    def grade(self):
        return self.cgrade

    def __str__(self):
        return f"cs{self.num} {self.cname} Grade:{self.cgrade} Credit Hours: {self.c_hr}"
```